# Getting error while generating project template using SF v2

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-error, sf

I am setting up a new machine and had to use the SF v2 cli.

While I am trying to use:

> sf project generate --name myproject

I get:

> Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: C:\Program Files (x86)\sf\client\node_modules@salesforce\templates\lib\templates\project\standard\ScratchDef.json

Any tips on that?

Comment: I would try to reinstall? What version is your Salesforce CLI?